# Mac CPU Info on Mac 10.6.4

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I tried these commands in terminal:

> system_profiler | grep CPU\ Speed
>
> system_profiler | grep Machine\ Model
>
> system_profiler | grep CPU\ Type

but it says:

> service: This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead

so what is the new command ?

Comment: Try `launchctl`?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be a better fit for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

On most *nix-type systems, /sbin/service is a simple shell script that runs something out of `/etc/init.d` with a minimal environment. It's more-or-less the same thing as saying

/etc/init.d *something* start/stop/status/whatever

So the common use pattern for /sbin/service is to start, stop, or restart daemons, but `launchctl` and `launchd` are the OS X new order for that sort of thing.

In fact, OS X doesn't even have init.d, so it has a compiled binary version of /sbin/service that does ... who knows what?

It looks like system_profiler needs to ask a daemon for status and something you have installed is still running /sbin/service to do so. I don't think there is an easy fix for this, but probably a software upgrade will eventually solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Those annoying messages are going to stderr, and the output you want is going to stdout.  I tried

```
system_profiler 2>/dev/null | grep Processor\ Speed
```

under 10.6.4 and got the output

```
  Processor Speed: 2.5 GHz
```

You didn't get any output to stdout because you searched for the wrong strings.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the non-OSX information, the service is also deprecated  on many flavors of Linux, often replaced with `systemd`. However, `systemd` doesn’t  use the old `init.d` system (as that system is really what is being deprecated).  If you can’t find any of your `rc/service` controls on your Linux box try using `systemctl`.